# Failed to call WL.Server.invokeProcedure - java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, adapter

We have MFP on Development(VM)  and Production (Google Cloud) environment. 
We are calling adapter which contains parameter which is large json object more than 1 MB.

While calling adapter mashup javascript to javascript on DEV env its working fine while on Google Could MFP its giving following error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)



[6/15/18 5:52:51:878 UTC] 00003978 com.ibm.mfp.server.js.adapter.internal.JavascriptManagerImpl E FWLST0904E: Exception was thrown while invoking procedure: setPlansData in adapter: RESTAdapter
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
    at com.ibm.mfp.server.js.adapter.internal.invocation.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation.invokeProcedure(JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor395.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.integration_js_1._c_anonymous_13(integration.js:590)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.integration_js_1.call(integration.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.RESTAdapter_impl_js_20._c_setPlansData_162(RESTAdapter-impl.js:9497)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.RESTAdapter_impl_js_20.call(RESTAdapter-impl.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:393)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3282)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.RESTAdapter_impl_js_20.call(RESTAdapter-impl.js)
    at com.ibm.mfp.server.js.adapter.internal.JavascriptManagerImpl.invokeFunction(JavascriptManagerImpl.java:280)
    at com.ibm.mfp.server.js.adapter.internal.JavascriptManagerImpl.invokeProcedure(JavascriptManagerImpl.java:187)
    at com.ibm.mfp.server.js.adapter.internal.invocation.JavascriptInvoker.invoke(JavascriptInvoker.java:57)
    at com.ibm.mfp.gen.JavascriptAdapterRestWrapperResource.setPlansDataPost(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:181)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:97)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:200)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:99)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:293)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:212)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:268)
    at com.ibm.mfp.server.java.adapter.shared.JAXRSSandbox$3.doFilter(JAXRSSandbox.java:579)
    at com.ibm.mfp.server.java.adapter.shared.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:86)
    at com.ibm.mfp.server.java.adapter.shared.JAXRSSandbox.handleRequest(JAXRSSandbox.java:584)
    at com.ibm.mfp.server.java.adapter.internal.rest.AdaptersEndpoint.adapterServing(AdaptersEndpoint.java:115)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor327.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1290)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:778)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:475)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1161)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:82)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:956)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:280)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.wrapHandlerAndExecute(HttpDispatcherLink.java:359)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:318)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:471)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:405)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:285)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:256)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:174)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:929)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1018)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:122)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:166)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingOutputStream.write(LoggingOutputStream.java:77)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.streamWrite(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.flushBuffer(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:135)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.writeLine(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:239)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriter.writeHeadLine(DefaultHttpRequestWriter.java:66)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriter.writeHeadLine(DefaultHttpRequestWriter.java:42)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageWriter.write(AbstractMessageWriter.java:109)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.sendRequestHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.sendRequestHeader(CPoolProxy.java:145)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:203)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at com.ibm.mfp.server.java.adapter.internal.beans.api.AdaptersApiImpl.internalExecuteAdapterRequest(AdaptersApiImpl.java:114)
    at com.ibm.mfp.server.java.adapter.internal.beans.api.AdaptersApiImpl.executeAdapterRequest(AdaptersApiImpl.java:95)
    at com.ibm.mfp.server.java.adapter.internal.beans.api.AdaptersApiImpl.executeAdapterRequest(AdaptersApiImpl.java:46)
    at com.ibm.mfp.server.js.adapter.internal.invocation.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation.invokeProcedure(JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation.java:250)
    ... 82 more
```

Not getting why its not working on GCP.

We are calling adapter mashup (Javascript to Javascript)

```
var inputData = {
                "custId": "dataPlans",
                "PLAN_DATA": FetchBcdpPlansResponse,
                "searchKey": "custId",
                "expire": REDIS_BCD_PLAN_EXP_TIME_SEC
            }


            var serviceResponse = MFP.Server.invokeProcedure({
                adapter: 'ServiceWrapperAdapter',
                procedure: 'storeInRedis',
                parameters: [inputData]
            });
```

Comment: Broken pipe can happen trying to write when the other end has closed it. It could be happening from the huge payload you are trying to push. Does it work if the payload is smaller?

Comment: Yes its working by reducing payload. But what can be the issue as with large payload its working on on-premise environment.